# Reactstrap Modal - Stylesheet Not Being Fully Applied With contentClassName Prop

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, reactstrap

I am using [reactstrap's](https://reactstrap.github.io/?path=/docs/components-modal--destructuring) `Modal` and I just want to **expand its size to 95% of the visible area**.

Currently, when applying the prop `size="xl"` to `Modal`, it is too small still for my needs.  So, I found a potential solution [on this page](https://dev.to/itz_giddy/the-right-way-to-resize-reactstrap-s-modal-component-302o) that showed applying a custom class coming from an external stylesheet into reactstrap Modal worked for him.

After following this advice, I succeeded in making the modal expand to 95% of visible area.  Unfortunately, refreshing the page caused the modal to snap back to size `xl`.  And so, I need a solution which reliably makes the reactstrap Modal apply the external stylesheet's styles and never 'snaps back' to `xl`.

**What I tried, and results...**

1. Adding the stylesheet to `index.html` as a `<link />` in the `/public` folder.
   I added this:  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/styles.css">`
   Result: *fail*.
2. I tried using `styled-components`.  This failed for me because I had no success after trying to wrap divs around the modal which contained my styles.  Perhaps there's a clever way of using `reactstrap Modal` and `styled-components` to create a `HOC` that can do this task?
   Result: *fail*.
3. Used React state and event handler and a button which, when clicked, applied and removed the custom class name I used `custom-modal-style`.  The way used it was like so...

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Button, Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter } from 'reactstrap';
import './styles.css'

const toggle = () => setModal(!modal);

const ProductWizard = () =>
{
    const [makeLarger, setMakeLarger] = useState(false);
    const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);

    return(
        <>
            <Button color="info" onClick={toggle}>Create Product</Button>
            <Modal 
                size="xl" 
                centered
                scrollable
                isOpen={modal} toggle={toggle} 
                contentClassName={ makeLarger ? "custom-modal-style" : null }
                // contentClassName="custom-modal-style" 
                >...</Modal>
        </>
    )
    
}
```

Here are the `styles.css` stylesheet contents...

```
    .custom-modal-style {
        position: fixed;
        left: 5px;
        width: 98%;
        right: 5px;
        max-height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        display: block;
    }
```

Result: *fails to expand to 95% of the screen size, although it did slightly enlarge (by margin of around 20px to 30px)*.

**Does anyone have a solution which causes the reactstrap `Modal` component to reliably expand to the dimensions of 95% of the screen size?**

Comment: You sure there's not other css that's overlapping? Check this sandbox, what you posted seems to be working. https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-bird-7tk31?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Well, I just renamed the class to `custom-modal-style-a` and I am getting the same result.

Comment: I began thinking perhaps it is just not reading `styles.css`, so I decided to test by adding a new class to the file.  I saw certain things change, like I changed `color` to `pink` under a new class `modal-modal` and it did change the text color so I can confirm it is reading from `styles.css`.  However, it's is completely ignoring the css mentioned in my post... `max-height`, `left`, `width`, etc.  It just IGNORES and I don't know why...

Comment: Did you click on the codesandbox link that I left? All those things work when changing the css.

Comment: @RolandoYera I just checked your codesandbox link but it's not demonstrating a modal expanded to the dimensions I mentioned.  It's opening just a small modal it appears but my code does that already.  What I need it to do is open the modal with its size expanded to around 95vh and 95vw but it only does that intermittently and not every time :(

Comment: Go into the css and change the width. I just changed it.

Comment: Here it is also with styled-components https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-clarke-wzcyj?file=/src/ProductWizard.js